# fragment placehoder in layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

Suppose I have several **fragments**:

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment { ... }

public class SecondFragment extends Fragment { ... }

public class ThirdFragment extends Fragment { ... }
```

I have also a main **activity**, its content is (`main.xml`):

```
<LinearLayout ...>

  <!-- How to have a fragment placehold without specify which fragment show here? -->
  <fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

My question is, in above layout file, how can I define a **fragment placeholder** without specify which fragment show here, and then **in My Activity java code**, inflate a proper fragment to the placeholder ?

Is it possible and how to do it?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It is possible.
In your main.xml, define a place holder for the fragment, let's call it "fragment_placeholder":

```
<LinearLayout ...>
 <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_placeholder" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In your activity, whenever you want to load your fragment:

```
YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder, fragment);
ft.commit();
```

Comment: ft.replace(...) should be changed to ft.add(...) in my case.

Comment: See this for more info: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [FragmentContainerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentContainerView). From the documentation:

> FragmentContainerView is a customized Layout designed specifically for
> Fragments. It extends FrameLayout, so it can reliably handle Fragment
> Transactions, and it also has additional features to coordinate with
> fragment behavior.

Example (also from the docs):

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
 </androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>
```